# Custom serializer output for nested relationship field in DRF serializer class

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am in little trouble while developing a web api's using [Django-Rest-Framework(DRF)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

### Problem Statement

I have two models `User` and `Review`.

#### models.py

```py
# Consider User model as `django.contrib.auth.models.User`
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Review model
class Review(models.Model):
    head = models.CharField()
    content = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and, i have two endpoints like this:

```
    /users/      - list of all users
    /users/<pk>  - detail of user
    /review/     - list of all reviews
    /review/<pk> - detail of review
```

I want my output like this:

```py
# /users/ 
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/users/1",
        "fisrt_name": "Adolf",
        "last_name": "Hitler",
        "email": "adolfhilter@xyz.com",
        "is_staff": false
        ........ # other fields
    },
    .........
    .........
]

# /reviews/
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/reviews/1",
        "head": "Head of Review",
        "content": "Content of Review",
        "user": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/users/1",
            "first_name": "Adolf",
            "last_name": "Hitler"
        },
        "is_deleted": false
    },
    .........
    .........
]
```

### My Solution

To achieve this form of output i created three serializers class, one is `UserSerializer` class , second one is `ReviewSerializer`, and thir one id `ReviewUserSerializer`.These classes are as follows:

#### serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Review
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', .....)

class ReviewUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class ReviewSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = ReviewUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('url', 'head', 'content', 'user')
```

So, now i want to know that ,

> Is there any other way which can avoid to create an extra separate serializer class(here is `ReviewUserSerializer`) for these type of situations?

If yes, then suggest me a solution with proper code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a SerializerMethodField?

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Review
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', .....)

class ReviewSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('url', 'head', 'content', 'user')

    def get_user(self, obj) :
        request = self.context['request']
        return {
          'url': reverse('user-detail',
                       kwargs={'pk': obj.user.id}, request=request),
          'first_name': obj.user.first_name,
          'last_name': obj.user.last_name,
        }
```

Comment: I didn't know that and it really works, but `url` field did not work in `get_user()`. **AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'url'**

Comment: Updated.  User reverse to get the url.  Passing the request allows it to get the full url.